# How to add Dynamic page in compose horizontal pager and to refresh the pager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
   @Composable
   fun viewPagerCompose(pageCount: Int, viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState,pageCount = pageCount) { page ->
        when (page) {
            0 -> {showChoiceList(viewModel = viewModel)}
            1 -> {FragmentMapInCompose()}
     }

   }
}
```

This is how I created the Viewpager and now I want to add page dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options, but generally you have to update some observable state that holds a list of items you want to show in the pager. This is example that adds a new page every time you click the button:

```
@Composable
fun ViewPagerCompose() {
  var items by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf("choiceList", "map")) }

  Column {
    HorizontalPager(pageCount = items.size) { index ->
      when (items[index]) {
        "choiceList" -> { ChoiceList() }
        "map" -> { FragmentMapInCompose() }
        "whatever" -> { Text("whatever") }
      }
    }
    Button(
      onClick = { items += "whatever" }
    ) { Text("Add page") }
  }
}
```

You'd want to create an `enum` or `sealed class` hierarchy to put into the list instead of strings, depending on your needs, but the principle is the same.

Comment: If items are getting updated in viewmodel , then do we have to redraw the pager.

Comment: It will work the same with viewmodel, you will just move the `items` into viewmodel, just without the `remember`. What do you mean by "redraw the pager"? In compose, it redraws (or rather recomposes) automatically when the params change.